# Grails excel-export overwrites template styles

Tags: excel, grails, export

According to the documentation, we should be able to load a template with styling, write data to it, then output the resultant data+styling.  However, each cell we write to has its formatting from the template removed, so only cells not written to still have the formatting. we can't use the "add" method as we don't have lists of domain objects with corresponding properties, we have an arbitrarily array of data.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
WebXlsxExporter xlsxExporter = new WebXlsxExporter(servletContext.getRealPath("/reporting/report_template.xlsx"))
xlsxExporter.putCellValue(0, 0, reportSchedule.report.title)
xlsxExporter.putCellValue(0, 3, new Date())
xlsxExporter.putCellValue(0, 6, response.time + "ms")

if (! response.rows.isEmpty()) {
    int row = 1
    headers = response.rows[0].keySet();

    headers.eachWithIndex() {item, i ->
        xlsxExporter.putCellValue(row, i, item.value.toString())
    };
    row++

    response.rows.each {line ->
        line.eachWithIndex { item, int i ->
            xlsxExporter.putCellValue(row, i, item.value.toString())
        }
        row++
    }
} else {
    xlsxExporter.putCellValue(2,1, "No Data")
}
xlsxExporter.save(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to be very generic and I'm sorry for that in advance but would it possible to just *"back up"* each cell style before you write the value to it and restore the style once you're finished with writing? Basically you'd do

```
def cellStyle = xlsxReporter.getCellAt(row, i).getCellStyle()
xlsxExporter.putCellValue(row, i, item.value.toString())
xlsxReporter.getCellAt(row, i).setCellStyle(cellStyle)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried this, but the getCellAt throws a null pointer exception if you call it before putCellValue.  I tried calling putCellValue again at the end, after setCellStyle, but this did nothing also.